# How to make a voltage vs amp-hour discharge curve

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, battery-operated, discharge

This is in regard with [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183019/how-to-make-a-discharge-curve) of mine, how do you make a discharge curve with the y-axis of voltage and x-axis of amp - hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just relabel the X axis. When you discharge at a constant current, the hours are directly proportional to the amp-hours.

For example, if you're discharging at 50 mA and your X-axis runs from 0 to 20 hours, you could simply relabel it as 0 to 1.0 A-h.

Comment: Ok, but when you say "discharging at 50mA," you mean the load is rated at 50 mA, right?

Comment: So, if I discharge my battery at say a load of 20mA, and it runs for 20 hours, then (like you said(, I could relabel the axis as 0 - 0.4 Ah?

Comment: Yes, and yes. It's really quite simple.

Comment: I have one more question: what is the process for the load selection, that is, is there a way to figure out what load you should use to make your discharge curve (based on the battery)?

Comment: Dave, the load would have to be constant right? A 28 mA LED won't do the job right?

Comment: You've asked a lot of closely-related questions in the past 8 hours. What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish? Are you familiar with the datasheets for commonly-available batteries?

Comment: Yes I am. I am making a zinc carbon battery of my own and want to test it. So I wanted to figure out its capacity by making a discharge curve. But s you know, I would also need to select and appropriate load for the battery, and then determine the cut off voltage. So these are the three things: capacity, load, and cutoff voltage of the battery. The only thing I don't know now is how to figure out the cutoff voltage of the battery.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion I am creating.

Comment: No problem, but if you would have explained this up front, you would have gotten more direct answers. You're going to have to determine the parameters for your battery through experimentation, using a number of different loads to evaluate its internal impedance and charge capacity. The cutoff voltage is basically an arbitrary determination based on when "most" of the capacity (anywhere from 90% to 99%) has been used up.